# "How to fix str.lslpit() functionality for user input to remove trailing spaces"

Tags: python-3.x, string

"I'm trying to remove trailing spaces from user_input string using str.lsplit() functionality"

## I have tried str.lsplit() for two cases

## case1:Taken the input message as string from user->Not getting result as expected

## case2: Hard coded input message as string->Got the result as expected

## MyCode

```
    '''string1 = str(input("Enter your message non case sensitive"))
       string2 = "    This is Test String2 to strip leading space"
       print ("str.lsplit() functionality is NOT WORKING as expected for 
       user input\n","user_Input String1\n",string1,"\nuser_output 
       String2\n",string1.lstrip())
       print ("str.lsplit() functionality is WORKING for hardcoded string 
       input\n","Input String2\n",string2,"\noutput 
       String2\n",string2.lstrip())
    '''
```

## Actual Results

```
     '''Enter your message non case sensitive "    This is Test String1 to 
        strip leading space"
        str.lsplit() functionality is NOT WORKING as expected for user 
        input
        user_Input String1
        "    This is Test String1 to strip leading space" 
        user_output String2
        "    This is Test String1 to strip leading space"
        str.lsplit() functionality is WORKING for hardcoded string input
        Input String2
            This is Test String2 to strip leading space 
        output String2
        This is Test String2 to strip leading space
        Process finished with exit code 0
       '''
```

## Expected results

Expecting to get the output by removing trailing spaces from the user_input scenario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very unclear what you are having trouble with. You mention `lsplit`, which isn't even a function. `split` is a function, but I'm sure you mean `lstrip`. Your code is very confusing. Try something like this, instead:

```
string1 = input("Enter your message non case sensitive: ") # Input always returns a str in Python 3
string2 = "    This is Test String2 to strip leading space"
print(f"string1               = '{string1}'")
print(f"string2               = '{string2}'")
print(f"string1 left stripped = '{string1.lstrip()}'")  
print(f"string2 left stripped = '{string2.lstrip()}'")
```

Here is the output when I entered `"  ASD   "`:

```
Enter your message non case sensitive:  ASD   
string1               = '  ASD   '
string2               = '    This is Test String2 to strip leading space'
string1 left stripped = 'ASD   '
string2 left stripped = 'This is Test String2 to strip leading space'
```

`lstrip` removes the *leading* whitespace, not the trailing. Use `rstrip` for that, or `strip` to remove both. Also note that in Python strings are immutable, so these functions won't change the string itself, rather they return a brand new string which you can then assign to the variable, like so:

```
string2 = "    This is Test String2 to strip leading space"
string2 = string2.lstrip()
```

Comment: Thanks @GordonAitchJay I got you 
I gave the input in " my message " format so its didn't worked for me by d way  thanks for your clear explanation.Have a Great day buddy